# Ubuntu 13.10 No Audio

Tags: sound, 13.10

All of my audio has worked fine beforehand, I have tried 'sudo rm ~/.pulse* ~/.config/pulse* ~/.asoundrc -R', with no results and I've checked alsamixer to see if the correct audiocard was selected. From what I can tell nothing is muted.

Comment: You might want to list what `lspci | grep Audio' says to know the name of your sound card.

Answer (score 0):

My Ubuntu also lost his voice after upgrade to 13.10.

I had similar problem with some old Ubuntu version and the solution still works in 13.10 for me:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```